# XSLT: xsi:schemaLocation is not showing on XML

Tags: xslt

I am trying to do a transformation but I am having an issue with the xsi:schemaLocation not showing on the XML result. I have searched all over why this is happening and I just can't seem to find it. Please help

Input XML

```
<asx:abap version="1.0" xmlns:asx="http://www.sap.com/abapxml">
<asx:values>
    <_--5CCLASS_--3DZCL_T4_NOM_--5CTYPE_--3DTT_SAP_REQ>
        <item>
            <TECHNICAL_KEY>00006000000000326391</TECHNICAL_KEY>
            <TSCARRIER>CPL</TSCARRIER>
            <MATERIAL>V2</MATERIAL>
            <PIPELINE_CYCLE>45</PIPELINE_CYCLE>
            <PIPELINE_SEQUENCE>1</PIPELINE_SEQUENCE>
            <CYCLE_YEAR>2012</CYCLE_YEAR>
            <SCD/>
            <NOM_NUMBER>CITV2451</NOM_NUMBER>
            <DATE_TIME>2012-06-20T00:00:00</DATE_TIME>
            <CREATE_DATE_TIME>2012-06-06T18:01:18</CREATE_DATE_TIME>
            <TOTAL_ITEMS>1 </TOTAL_ITEMS>
            <T4NOMNR/>
            <ITEM_NUMBER>0000000010</ITEM_NUMBER>
            <ITEM_DETAIL_CHANGE_CODE/>
            <PIPELINE_EVENT>Delivery</PIPELINE_EVENT>
            <PIPELINE_EVENT_AFFECT>Decrease</PIPELINE_EVENT_AFFECT>
            <QUANTITY>25000.00</QUANTITY>
            <UOM>BR</UOM>
            <LOCATION>AHT</LOCATION>
            <LOCATION_PARTNER>AHT</LOCATION_PARTNER>
            <CONTRACT_PARTNER/>
            <SUPPLIER/>
            <TANKAGE_PARTNER>KM1</TANKAGE_PARTNER>
            <CONSIGNEE_PARTNER>CIT</CONSIGNEE_PARTNER>
            <CONS_SUPPLIER>Consignee</CONS_SUPPLIER>
            <TRANSPURIND>Add</TRANSPURIND>
            <VERSION>1</VERSION>
            <PARTROLEIND>Shipper</PARTROLEIND>
            <SHIPPARTID>CIT</SHIPPARTID>
            <PART_IDENTIFIER>AssignedByCarrier</PART_IDENTIFIER>
            <PROD_IDENTIFIER>AssignedByMarketplace</PROD_IDENTIFIER>
            <PART_TANKAGE>Tankage</PART_TANKAGE>
            <CARRIER_STRING>Carrier</CARRIER_STRING>
            <SHIPNOMNRSTRING>ShipperNominationNumber</SHIPNOMNRSTRING>
        </item>
    </_--5CCLASS_--3DZCL_T4_NOM_--5CTYPE_--3DTT_SAP_REQ>
</asx:values>
```

XSLT Code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.api.org/pidXML/v1.2" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:pidx="http://www.api.org/pidXML/v1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.api.org/pidXML/v1.2 https://www.transport4.com/xml/schemas/PipelineNominationCreateV1-3.xsd">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="pidx:PipelineNominationCreate">
            <xsl:attribute name="pidx:documentIdentifier"><xsl:value-of select="//TECHNICAL_KEY"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="pidx:transactionPurposeIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="//TRANSPURIND"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="pidx:version"><xsl:value-of select="//VERSION"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="pidx:PipelineNominationCreateProperties">
                <xsl:element name="pidx:CreatedByPartner">
                    <xsl:element name="pidx:PartnerInformation">
                        <xsl:attribute name="partnerRoleIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="//PARTROLEIND"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:element name="pidx:PartnerIdentifier">
                            <xsl:attribute name="partnerIdentifierIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="//PART_IDENTIFIER"/></xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="//SHIPPARTID"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="pidx:EventDateTime">
                        <xsl:value-of select="//CREATE_DATE_TIME"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="pidx:PartnerInformation">
                    <xsl:attribute name="partnerRoleIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="//PARTROLEIND"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:element name="pidx:PartnerIdentifier">
                        <xsl:attribute name="partnerIdentifierIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="//PART_IDENTIFIER"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//SHIPPARTID"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="pidx:PartnerInformation">
                    <xsl:attribute name="partnerRoleIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="//CARRIER_STRING"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:element name="pidx:PartnerIdentifier">
                        <xsl:attribute name="partnerIdentifierIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="//PART_IDENTIFIER"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//TSCARRIER"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="pidx:ProductInformation">
                    <xsl:element name="pidx:ProductIdentifier">
                        <xsl:attribute name="assigningOrganization"><xsl:value-of select="//PROD_IDENTIFIER"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//MATERIAL"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="pidx:PipelineCycle">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//PIPELINE_CYCLE"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="pidx:PipelineCycleYear">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//CYCLE_YEAR"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="pidx:PipelineSequence">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//PIPLELINE_SEQUENCE"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="pidx:PipelineSCD">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//SCD"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="pidx:ReferenceInformation">
                    <xsl:attribute name="referenceInformationIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="//SHIPNOMNRSTRING"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:element name="pidx:ReferenceNumber">
                        <xsl:value-of select="//NOM_NUMBER"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="pidx:Description">
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="pidx:PipelineNominationCreateDetails">
                <xsl:for-each select="//item">
                    <xsl:element name="pidx:PipelineNominationCreateLineItem">
                        <xsl:element name="pidx:LineItemNumber">
                            <xsl:value-of select="ITEM_NUMBER"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="pidx:LineItemNominationQuantity">
                            <xsl:element name="pidx:Quantity">
                                <xsl:value-of select="QUANTITY"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                            <xsl:element name="pidx:UnitOfMeasureCode">
                                <xsl:value-of select="UOM"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="pidx:PartnerInformation">
                            <xsl:attribute name="partnerRoleIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="CONS_SUPPLIER"/></xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:element name="pidx:PartnerIdentifier">
                                <xsl:attribute name="partnerIdentifierIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="//PART_IDENTIFIER"/></xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:value-of select="CONSIGNEE_PARTNER"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="pidx:PartnerInformation">
                            <xsl:attribute name="partnerRoleIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="PART_TANKAGE"/></xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:element name="pidx:PartnerIdentifier">
                                <xsl:attribute name="partnerIdentifierIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="//PART_IDENTIFIER"/></xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:value-of select="TANKAGE_PARTNER"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="pidx:ScheduleStartDateTime">
                            <xsl:value-of select="DATE_TIME"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="pidx:ScheduleRequestDateTime">
                    </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="pidx:PipelineEventInformation">
                            <xsl:element name="pidx:PipelineEvent">
                                <xsl:value-of select="PIPELINE_EVENT"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                            <xsl:element name="pidx:PipelineEventVolumeAffect">
                                <xsl:value-of select="PIPELINE_EVENT_AFFECT"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="pidx:CustodyLocationInformation">
                            <xsl:element name="pidx:CustodyLocationIdentifier">
                                <xsl:attribute name="identifierIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="//PART_IDENTIFIER"/></xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:value-of select="LOCATION_PARTNER"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="pidx:ReferenceInformation">
                            <xsl:attribute name="referenceInformationIndicator">
                        </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:element name="pidx:ReferenceNumber">
                        </xsl:element>
                            <xsl:element name="pidx:Description">
                        </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="pidx:Comment">
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="pidx:PipelineNominationCreateSummary">
                <xsl:element name="pidx:TotalLineItems">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//TOTAL_ITEMS"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result XML with missing schemaLocation

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<pidx:PipelineNominationCreate xmlns:pidx="http://www.api.org/pidXML/v1.2" xmlns="http://www.api.org/pidXML/v1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" pidx:documentIdentifier="00006000000000326391" pidx:transactionPurposeIndicator="Add" pidx:version="1">
    <pidx:PipelineNominationCreateProperties>
        <pidx:CreatedByPartner>
            <pidx:PartnerInformation partnerRoleIndicator="Shipper">
                <pidx:PartnerIdentifier partnerIdentifierIndicator="AssignedByCarrier">CIT</pidx:PartnerIdentifier>
            </pidx:PartnerInformation>
            <pidx:EventDateTime>2012-06-07T15:55:35</pidx:EventDateTime>
        </pidx:CreatedByPartner>
        <pidx:PartnerInformation partnerRoleIndicator="Shipper">
            <pidx:PartnerIdentifier partnerIdentifierIndicator="AssignedByCarrier">CIT</pidx:PartnerIdentifier>
        </pidx:PartnerInformation>
        <pidx:PartnerInformation partnerRoleIndicator="Carrier">
            <pidx:PartnerIdentifier partnerIdentifierIndicator="AssignedByCarrier">CPL</pidx:PartnerIdentifier>
        </pidx:PartnerInformation>
        <pidx:ProductInformation>
            <pidx:ProductIdentifier assigningOrganization="AssignedByMarketplace">V2</pidx:ProductIdentifier>
        </pidx:ProductInformation>
        <pidx:PipelineCycle>45</pidx:PipelineCycle>
        <pidx:PipelineCycleYear>2012</pidx:PipelineCycleYear>
        <pidx:PipelineSequence/>
        <pidx:PipelineSCD/>
        <pidx:ReferenceInformation referenceInformationIndicator="ShipperNominationNumber">
            <pidx:ReferenceNumber>CITV2451</pidx:ReferenceNumber>
            <pidx:Description/>
        </pidx:ReferenceInformation>
    </pidx:PipelineNominationCreateProperties>
    <pidx:PipelineNominationCreateDetails>
        <pidx:PipelineNominationCreateLineItem>
            <pidx:LineItemNumber>0000000010</pidx:LineItemNumber>
            <pidx:LineItemNominationQuantity>
                <pidx:Quantity>25000.0</pidx:Quantity>
                <pidx:UnitOfMeasureCode>BR</pidx:UnitOfMeasureCode>
            </pidx:LineItemNominationQuantity>
            <pidx:PartnerInformation partnerRoleIndicator="Consignee">
                <pidx:PartnerIdentifier partnerIdentifierIndicator="AssignedByCarrier">CIT</pidx:PartnerIdentifier>
            </pidx:PartnerInformation>
            <pidx:PartnerInformation partnerRoleIndicator="Tankage">
                <pidx:PartnerIdentifier partnerIdentifierIndicator="AssignedByCarrier">KM1</pidx:PartnerIdentifier>
            </pidx:PartnerInformation>
            <pidx:ScheduleStartDateTime>2012-06-20T00:00:00</pidx:ScheduleStartDateTime>
            <pidx:ScheduleRequestDateTime/>
            <pidx:PipelineEventInformation>
                <pidx:PipelineEvent>Delivery</pidx:PipelineEvent>
                <pidx:PipelineEventVolumeAffect>Decrease</pidx:PipelineEventVolumeAffect>
            </pidx:PipelineEventInformation>
            <pidx:CustodyLocationInformation>
                <pidx:CustodyLocationIdentifier identifierIndicator="AssignedByCarrier">AHT</pidx:CustodyLocationIdentifier>
            </pidx:CustodyLocationInformation>
            <pidx:ReferenceInformation referenceInformationIndicator="">
                <pidx:ReferenceNumber/>
                <pidx:Description/>
            </pidx:ReferenceInformation>
            <pidx:Comment/>
        </pidx:PipelineNominationCreateLineItem>
    </pidx:PipelineNominationCreateDetails>
    <pidx:PipelineNominationCreateSummary>
        <pidx:TotalLineItems>1 </pidx:TotalLineItems>
    </pidx:PipelineNominationCreateSummary>
</pidx:PipelineNominationCreate>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what problem you are having...  Namespaces will be in the resulting document IF they are used, but nothing in your output doc uses the xsi namespace...  Everything seems to be pidx...

Answer (score 8):

You have defined `xsi:schemaLocation` in your XSLT document, but nowhere in your XSLT do you attempt to create it in the XML document.  It will not automatically be added to your output document. You will need to create it.

You can copy the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute from the XSLT document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns="http://www.api.org/pidXML/v1.2" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:pidx="http://www.api.org/pidXML/v1.2" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.api.org/pidXML/v1.2 https://www.transport4.com/xml/schemas/PipelineNominationCreateV1-3.xsd">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="pidx:PipelineNominationCreate">
            <xsl:copy-of select="document('')/*/@xsi:schemaLocation"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding/copying the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute explicitely in the XSLT, like you would add/copy any other attribute? For example, after the line

```
<xsl:element name="pidx:PipelineNominationCreate">
```

try adding this:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/node()/@*[local-name()='schemaLocation']"/>
```

This should copy any `schemaLocation` attributes (regardless of their namespace prefix) from the root node of the original document.

Answer (score 2):

Like other people have said, the attribute isn't present in the output because you make no attempt to put it there.

Were you aware that your code could be much less verbose if you use literal result elements? For example, this:

```
<xsl:element name="pidx:PipelineNominationCreate">
            <xsl:attribute name="pidx:documentIdentifier"><xsl:value-of select="//TECHNICAL_KEY"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="pidx:transactionPurposeIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="//TRANSPURIND"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="pidx:version"><xsl:value-of select="//VERSION"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="pidx:PipelineNominationCreateProperties">
                <xsl:element name="pidx:CreatedByPartner">
                    <xsl:element name="pidx:PartnerInformation">
                        <xsl:attribute name="partnerRoleIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="//PARTROLEIND"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:element name="pidx:PartnerIdentifier">
                            <xsl:attribute name="partnerIdentifierIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="//PART_IDENTIFIER"/></xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="//SHIPPARTID"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="pidx:EventDateTime">
                        <xsl:value-of select="//CREATE_DATE_TIME"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
```

can be rewritten like this:

```
<pidx:PipelineNominationCreate 
  pidx:documentIdentifier="{//TECHNICAL_KEY}"
  pidx:transactionPurposeIndicator="{//TRANSPURIND}"
  pidx:version="{//VERSION}">
  <pidx:PipelineNominationCreateProperties>
     <pidx:CreatedByPartner>
        <pidx:PartnerInformation partnerRoleIndicator="{//PARTROLEIND}">
            <pidx:PartnerIdentifier 
                partnerIdentifierIndicator="{//PART_IDENTIFIER}">
                <xsl:value-of select="//SHIPPARTID"/>
            </pidx:PartnerIdentifier>
        </pidx:PartnerInformation>
        <pidx:EventDateTime>
            <xsl:value-of select="//CREATE_DATE_TIME"/>
        </pidx:EventDateTime>
```

which is so much more readable.

Comment: Thanks! It now shows, and also thanks for all the advise, I will put it to good use.